# csv file is empty after creating and downloading it using react-csv

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, use-effect

I built a small react app that takes data and changes it in some way, then downloads it to a csv file. When I download the file the csv is empty. Here is my code:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const downloadBtn = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data.length) {
        downloadBtn.current.link.click();
    }
  }, [data])

const compressData = () => {
    const compressedData = [];
    // do something with data
    setData(compressedData);
  }

return( 
    <button className="btn btn-light btn-outline-secondary" onClick={compressData}>Compress Transactions</button>
    <CSVLink
      ref={downloadBtn}
      className="btn btn-light btn-outline-secondary d-none" // button is hidden
      filename="transactions.csv"
      data={data}>Compress Transactions</CSVLink>
)
```

but if I put the click inside a setTimeout like this it works:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    downloadBtn.current.link.click();
}, 1);
```

I'd really like to know why it happens, and maybe hear about a better way to deal with it.